# Creating type inside index in elastic search through rest high level client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am using rest high level client elastic search in my JAVA application. Document can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.2/java-rest-high.html).
In my application at startup I am deleting index named "posts" where Elasticsearch datas are stored and creating again Index "posts" following this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.2/java-rest-high-create-index.html)

```
CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("posts");
```

But, Inside index I need to create one type named "doc". Which is not mentioned in the website.
Temporary fix is when I am posting some data following this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.2/java-rest-high-document-index.html) it is creating type

```
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
jsonMap.put("user", "kimchy");
jsonMap.put("postDate", new Date());
jsonMap.put("message", "trying out Elasticsearch");
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("posts", "doc", "1")
    .source(jsonMap);
```

But, in this process when I am posting only  then I can able to create type "doc". If I am not posting and trying to hit controller which calls data frmo index "posts" and type "doc". It gives error as "doc" type is not there.

Anyone hava any idea how to create type using rest high level client ES in java

Comment: Similary if I don't do CreateIndex also it will create when I post data.

Answer (score 1):

By type you mean document type?

What about the second section [Index Mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.2/java-rest-high-create-index.html#_index_mappings) in the link you provided? 
Does this not work for you?

Comment: You are right this will create type "tweet" inside index "twitter",  but here you need to map, but In my case I am not mapping. I want to store any type of Document

Comment: For now, I will try to keep second field in method blank like request.mapping("tweet", "", XContentType.JSON); Will see weather it will create and it will allow me to store anything

Comment: I think it is possible, as when creating index, type in elastic search or in kibana dev console We can give PUT index/doc like that, and rest client also parsing like that most probably

Comment: > I want to store any type of Document 
If you want to store different kinds of documents it's better to store them in different indices. In fact, [types are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html).

Comment: Got it. I will make different indices. But, how people were doing like in my use case. How they were doing. Any Idea? Just curious

Comment: Let's see one case, when you want to delete using DeleteRequest where the line is restHighLevelClient.delete(new DeleteRequest(INDEX, TYPE, searchHit[i].getId()), RequestOptions.DEFAULT). Now if I don't have any type to give what should I give? if I will give null it will show exception. Url is of DeleteRequest Javadoc https://textuploader.com/1516i

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set type to "_doc" to make it working with ES7.6

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to insert documents through API then this way will much more easy for you to do anything similar API (DELETE,POST,PUT...)
First, you will need RestHighLevelClient and all you have to do

```
String index = "/indexName/_doc"; <- Your path or type here
Request request = new Request("POST", index); <- Your method
request.setJsonEntity(
      "{ \"message\": \" example add insert\" }" <- Your request body
);

client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest(request);
```

This will execute like how API does.